# htaccess rewrite log to multiple php files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need help in solving the issue with my htaccess rewrite for multiple php file. No matter what I do the the last condition of vod movie is not working and always point to the first php file new.php . The first three are working fine because they point to same file. I have read in here that they shouldn't  be ambiguous but I don't know how to do it or solve it. Please help me thanks.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^live/([^/]*)/([^.]*)/([^/]*)\.m3u8/?$ new.php?code=$1&c=$3&type=m3u8 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^live/([^/]*)/([^.]*)/([^/]*)\.ts/?$ new.php?code=$1&c=$3&type=ts [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^.]*)/([^/]*)?$ new.php?code=$1&c=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]*)/([^.]*)/([^/]*)\.mp4/?$ /vod.php?code=$1&c=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess file. Could you please mention which URL is not getting redirected?

Comment: The last one http://test.com/movie/22/22/3.mp4 to http://test.com/vod.php?code=22&c=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on your shown samples only. Please do clear your browser cache before testing URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^live/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^.]*)\.m3u8/?$ new.php?code=$1&c=$3&type=m3u8 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^live/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^.]*)\.ts/?$ new.php?code=$1&c=$3&type=ts [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^.]*)\.mp4/?$ vod.php?code=$1&c=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ new.php?code=$1&c=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Wow, you are the best! Thank you

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim, Hey I have fixed your `movie` rule whose regex was wrongly written too, I tested it and it is working fine now. One question I have what is that Rule 4th one in my Rules(starting with `^([^/]*)`)? Is that working fine for you?

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim, ok great, your welcome. So all the Rules are working right? Because I had little doubt on the 4th rule as I mentioned on my previous comment.

Comment: It is behaving as expected. Thanks again

Comment: @AhmedIbrahim, cool, glad to hear. I have also regex of your links cheers and happy learning keep sharing good questions and answers cheers, good night.